# ASP.NET StreamWriter not working intermittent

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, ftp, streamwriter

We are having an issue where we have a function which is called to create the FTP settings file, however sometimes this function is never called (as the FTP settings file never exists) and this issue is intermittent.  This function is invoked after

```
  Directory.CreateDirectory(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(UploadPath));
  public bool GenerateFTPSettings()
{
    try
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UploadPath"]) + @"\ftp_settings.ftp"))
        {
            file.WriteLine(string.Format("user {0}",ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPUserName"]));
            file.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPPassword"]);
            file.WriteLine(string.Format("QUOTE SITE LRECL=80 RECFM=FB CY PRI={0} SEC={1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PRI"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SEC"]));
            file.WriteLine("BIN");
            file.WriteLine(string.Format("put {0}\\NEW FILE'FTPP.Z.T.{1}.{2}.INT'", HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["UploadPath"]),
              ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPUserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailboxID"]));
            file.WriteLine("QUIT");
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorHandler.WriteError(ex, "Upload"); 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two things it might be. Make sure to flush your stream like so:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("somefile")
{
    //write to the stream
    file.Flush();
}
```

Also are you sure that the session has a value:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["UploadPath"]
```

Is it always populated or perhaps is it being lost from the session? I would split out the logic to make sure it is set like so:

```
string uploadPath = HttpContext.Current.Session["UploadPath"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    //write to the file
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the session always has a value as this value is being used later to generate further files.. Only when generating the FTP settings file the issue occurs..